# Conversion with UTC

Tags: excel

I'm having problems having the accurate time convert in excel. I am currently in PDT zone running into an issue when I convert time greater than 5 pm to UTC time excel adds a one in front of the decimal number instead of changing it to a decimal  eg 6 pm should convert to 0.75 but instead converts it to 1.04166666666667 I've tried everything I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Times (and Dates) in Excel are measured from 00:00:00 on 1899/12/31* where a day is 1, an hour is 1/24, a minute is 1/24/60 etc.
1.0416666667 = 1 day and 1 hour - 25 hours.
6pm (= 18 hours) + 7 hours = 25 hours.
PDT is UTC-7.
If you use a number format hh:mm then you will see hours and minutes.
If you instead want fractions of a day, it looks as though you need to do (x-7/24).

- Microsoft meant it to be from 1900/01/01 but didn't realise that 1900 was NOT a leap-year, so from 1900/03/01 it's from 1899/12/31.

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your answer are you saying I should multiply the cell value by -7/24

Comment: I was using x as a variable, not a multiplier! You want to subtract 7/24.